# How to Empty Internal Message Queue in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have WSO2 APIM as our API Gateway (currently 2.6.0, in process of upgrading to 4.2.0).  We noticed it was running heavy where it shouldn't be.  The machine in question is for a client who has not yet gone live, so apart from the occasional test user, nothing is calling it but the APIM was still consuming 300% CPU.  Looking at the wso2carbon.log there were log messages just flying by, then a short pause, then flying by again.  I tried to see how many messages there were per minute but the whole log file was filled in one minute (33826 lines to be exact).  Then nothing for two minutes then the exact same number again with a new timestamp (again, all within the same minute)

[image: lines per minute in log file]

All of the messages in the log were like

```
TID: [] [] [2023-07-11 09:32:54,196] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.kernel.slot.DeliveryTaskExceptionHandler} -  Error occurred while processing task. Task id AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:vifpredg1.hosting.carus.com/192.168.160.2 {org.wso2.andes.kernel.slot.DeliveryTaskExceptionHandler}
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried restarting the APIM service but it just went back to the same state after start-up.

It looks like the internal message queue is full of messages that are invalid.  Assume they are then getting cycled around again when they fail.

**Primary question: How can I empty this queue or is there some other way to reset it to make it behave?**

Secondary question: Why is it happening and how can we prevent it?